# table "X" has no column named "Y"

Tags: android-sqlite

My application is failing when I try and insert a record into my table named "reminders" (see logcat below). I've looked at 20+ similar posts but I haven't been able to spot my error. It's probably an obvious mistake but I just can find it.

LogCat:

```
02-22 14:10:25.884: E/SQLiteLog(2638): (1) table reminders has no column named title
02-22 14:11:22.935: D/dalvikvm(2638): threadid=11: still suspended after undo (sc=1      dc=1)
02-22 14:11:34.684: W/dalvikvm(2638): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught   exception (group=0x40a13300)
02-22 14:11:34.684: D/dalvikvm(2638): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
02-22 14:11:39.263: D/dalvikvm(2638): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
02-22 14:11:40.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2638): FATAL EXCEPTION: ModernAsyncTask #1
02-22 14:11:40.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2638): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-22 14:11:40.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$3.done(ModernAsyncTask.java:137)
02-22 14:11:40.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
02-22 14:11:40.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
02-22 14:11:40.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
02-22 14:11:40.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
02-22 14:11:40.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
02-22 14:11:40.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
02-22 14:11:40.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-22 14:11:40.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2638): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown Uri: content://com.example.android.taskreminder.ReminderProvider/reminder
02-22 14:11:40.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at com.example.taskreminder.ReminderProvider.query(ReminderProvider.java:138)
02-22 14:11:40.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:652)
02-22 14:11:40.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:189)
02-22 14:11:40.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:370)
02-22 14:11:40.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:313)
02-22 14:11:40.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:49)
02-22 14:11:40.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:35)
02-22 14:11:40.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:240)
02-22 14:11:40.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:51)
02-22 14:11:40.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:40)
02-22 14:11:40.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$2.call(ModernAsyncTask.java:123)
02-22 14:11:40.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
02-22 14:11:40.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     ... 4 more
02-22 14:11:40.333: D/dalvikvm(2638): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
02-22 14:11:40.473: D/dalvikvm(2638): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
02-22 14:11:40.517: D/dalvikvm(2638): GC_CONCURRENT freed 233K, 3% free 11200K/11527K, paused 91ms+91ms, total 260ms
02-22 14:11:51.376: I/Process(2638): Sending signal. PID: 2638 SIG: 9
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {      

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "
            + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + COLUMN_ROWID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_TITLE
            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COLUMN_BODY + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_DATE_TIME + " INTEGER NOT NULL);";


    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    // Called when the database is created for the first time
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);            
    }

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    // Calls getWritableDataBase() on a DatabaseHelper object
    mDb = new DatabaseHelper(getContext()).getWritableDatabase();
    return true;        
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "
            + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + COLUMN_ROWID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_TITLE
            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COLUMN_BODY + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_DATE_TIME + " INTEGER NOT NULL);";


    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);            
    }
          }

   public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {       
    values.remove(ReminderProvider.COLUMN_ROWID);
    long id = mDb.insertOrThrow(ReminderProvider.DATABASE_TABLE, null, Values);
       getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
       return ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri, id);
}
```

Below is the value of the String DATABASE_CREATE (taken from debugger) that is passed into the db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE) call above.

CREATE TABLE reminders (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT NOT NULL, body TEXT NOT NULL, reminder_date_time INTEGER NOT NULL);

It looks correct to me unless I'm missing something.

Is there anyway to programatically (via methods) retrieve the schema of the DB after you've created it (and display via log.d()) so that you can confirm that it was created with the appropriate columns? I tried using SQLite3 commands in the shell. It appears that the  database exists (i.e., using the .databases command I could see a "file" of the name /data/data/com.example.taskreminder/databases/data.db). However when i tried looking at the table (via .tables command) i didn't get any results...but not really sure I'm using it correctly. Any suggestions for steps I could use to diagnose this type of problem?

Btw this is the first time I've used this forum...so not sure if I've used the

thanks.

Comment: If you can access the DB via the command line `sqlite3` tool, that's the best approach.  Do ".schema reminders" to see how "reminders" is defined.  (".tables" should show you all the tables in the DB.)

Comment: (Retrieving the schema programmatically is possible but is a PITA.)

Comment: (To do it programmatically use the "PRAGMA table_info(<table_name>)" statement.)

Comment: Hot Licks..thanks for the responses. I'm new to stackoverflow...I set my SO profile to get an email anytime someone posted something re: my question but I never received an email so I assumed no one had responded and somehow i didn't see your responses when I checked my question manually..so I'm only just seeing your responses today.

Comment: So here is where i am...thinking that I wasn't getting any responses I just continued to try different things an search for the error. Unfortunately I found the error messages generated in the LogCat to be pretty obscure (e.g., ModernAsyncTask #1...huh). From the message I assumed that the problem was with my SQL statement...so I tried changing a few things...eg. removed space between DATABASE_TABLE and opening paren...not sure if that made a difference or not..but eventually I found my mistake...Authority statement in code and manifest was incorrect. (continued)

Comment: Can't see how an error message like "MondernAsyncTask #1" could possible help me find this simple error...it makes me lose hope of every finding more subtle/difficult errors that I might introduced to an app.   Maybe if I was more experienced it would have been obvious to me????  Argh!

Comment: Having solved my own problem I tried once again to use the sqlite3 command tool (adb -s emulator-5554 shell) to now see if my ".schema reminders" would now in fact show me the columns of my database table "reminders"...but all i get is the command that I entered ".schema reminders". But if I do a ".databases" command I get two lines in my results.."main" which "points" to the file location of my database "/data/data/com.example.taskreminder/databases/data.db" and a temp line with no file location. However, none of the other commands (.dump, .schema) seem to work. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the pointers re: PRAGMA I'll investigate this once I get the sqlite3 commands to work.